# Android how to update 2nd tab according to 1st tab input?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have build 2 tabs using `Fragment`. 1st tab has a `EditText` and a `button`. If user input something in the `EditText` and click on the `button` it goes to 2nd tab. `onButtonClick` I have set to show 2nd tab but my value is not being updated. Although I have successfully written the 1st tab value in `session`. But don't know how to update the 2nd tab? How to rebuild the 2nd tab?

Added my code here:

In FragmentA I onButtonClick I have called this function:

```
private void goToFragmentB(String 1stTabValue)
{
    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
       // My 2nd tab has a TextView where I need to set the 1stTabValue. What should be the code
       // to set 1stTabValue in 2nd tab
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Tab will not refresh because Intent will be called for the first time only.. While adding tabs you will set intent add this flag there `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Example :

```
 Intent i = new Intent().setClass(this, YourClass.class)
.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

---

You Can use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), Store the input values in stored preferences and get in the second Tab

Comment: I have already added `SharedPreferences` and stored the preferences. Also assigned the value in a `TextView` of 2nd tab. But 2nd tab is not being updated. I found the reason is `FragmentActivity` is creating both the `ViewPages` at the beginning. Help me to know how I can update the 2nd tab when I click on the button on 1st tab?

Comment: Tab will not refresh because Intent will be called for the first time only.. While adding tabs you will set intent add this flag there addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: Here is my addTab code. Please help how to add this flag. I tried some but still can't get the way                                                 `for (int i = 0; i < mCashSalesPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
 actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
        .setText(mCashSalesPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
        .setTabListener(this));
}'

Comment: You are probably implementing Actionbar.TabLister, when you implement it you need to override 3 methods ontabselected, ontabreselected and ontabunselected, ** On onTabReselected(), call a method on your existing fragment that causes it to refresh its contents **

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in the activity which holds the fragment. I Hope, your next fragment will be using the same activity. But this method will not store your data persistently, If the activity is closed all your previous data is wiped out.

If you would need the data to be persistent then you would have to use Shared Preferences. Data will be stored inside your application folder, under shared_pref folder. It is stored as key-value pairs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this while adding your tab

```
  private void addTab(int drawableId,String name, Class<?> c)
{

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(name);

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView text = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
    text.setText(name);
    tabHost.setTag(name);
    tabHost.addTab(spec
            .setIndicator(tabIndicator)
            .setContent(new Intent(this, c)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
}
```

This Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will refresh your tab everytime when you hits your tab

and for storing value, use shared preference or database , its all about your choice