# How to re-create activity each time the tab is visited

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I have a `TabActivity`, and I want to re-create the activity with the tab is visited(calling the content of `onCreate()` each visit) . how ?

Comment: You can use onResume() method. It will load its contain each time :)

Comment: Finish the current activity and invoke an intent for your activity using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` - see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ....

```
this.finish(); // this is instance of TabActivity
```

.... to close the current one and create a new intent using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) 
startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit:**
`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` seems in fact to work as well <del>will probably not work, because</del> though it is intended to bring an existing activity <del>is just brought</del> to front (without recreation).

Check out [this](http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/) for more.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey down voter - this is definitely working, so where is your problem?

Comment: Have you ever work with tabs? check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967384/activity-in-tabactivity-doesnt-run-oncreate-method-when-clicked-second-time/15967633#15967633

Comment: Both solutions work (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) - I tested it based on http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: It's ok..don't worry..I have learned something from you and you have learned something from me.. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onResume()
```

This method is called every time an activity comes to the foreground. So all you need to do is to override this method

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
   // do your stuffs
}
```

TO learn more about activity lifecycle see this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Now you want to call onCreate each time, it seems you have some initializing task each time the acitivity comes to the foreground. So My suggestion is to use the initialization things in onResume instead of onCreate.

Comment: But this doesn't call onCreate

Comment: why do you need to call oncreate??

Comment: His requirement is restart his activity. mean he want that stuff in onCreate to execute when he comeback to activity by selecting tab.

Comment: @Pragnani i can understand that ... Thats why I am suggesting him to do things in onResume instead of onCreate

Comment: I know that, I too have used onResume when I first worked with tabs, but later I realize. I am not supporting my answer but think once setting a simple flag will do the trick instead of writing the stuff in onResume. Ok

Comment: yup I think your answer is also helpful .. as it is accepted in another question .. just another different approach .. I have o problem with it too .. may be the downvoter have the problem :) .. +1 for you

Comment: Thanks..This is not the first time I have answered this check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151960/android-how-to-update-2nd-tab-according-to-1st-tab-input also and more but I haven't got their links

Answer (score 1):

Before starting intent of each Tab, set Intent flag "clear top".

i.e

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

check my answer for reference in this question  [activity-in-tabactivity-doesnt-run-oncreate-method-when-clicked-second-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967384/activity-in-tabactivity-doesnt-run-oncreate-method-when-clicked-second-time/15967633#15967633)

Comment: Let me know the reason for downvote...This should work..Check my previous answer link for reference..I never care for downvote

Comment: I tested it based on the example at http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html; for some reason it seems in fact to work, though this is not according the specification (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Anyhow, I wouldn't dare to rely on it (unfortunately I couldn't reject my downvote) ...

Comment: @Trinimon I am asking the same you can use `clear_top` flag, as you said there is a specification, I haves said about that But I have forgot to include `No`  that change the meaning.. :P it is originally starts like `There is No specification..`